# Python error: Tuple has no attribute split

Tags: python

**is there an easy fix problem here or is it more complex?.**

```
AdressBook  = '/home/bookworm/AdressBook.txt'
contacts = {}
bob = open(AdressBook, 'r')
file = bob.read()
for line in file:
    import csv
    with open(AdressBook) as file:
        readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
        for row in readCSV:
            name = row[0]
            contact = row[1]
        myLine = name,contact
        myContact = myLine.split(',')
        contacts[myContact[0]] = myContact[1]
```

**I am now adding the rest of the code so that you might be able to tell if there are any problems in the data that causes the tuple.**

```
def write():
    Data = open(AdressBook,'w')
    for name, many in contacts.items():
        Data.write(name + ',' + many + '\n')
    Data.close()

def read():
    Data = open(AdressBook, 'r')
    stuff = Data.read()
    print(stuff)
    Data.close()
    return stuff
```

**This is the user stuff. It uses the dict contacts**

```
user = input('Would you like to acess your adress book?')
if user == 'yes' or 'yep' or 'y' or 'Yes' or 'YES!' or 'YES' or 'Yurp' 
or 'Yeppers' or 'si'or'1':
    while user != 5:
        user = input('''Select One:
Press 1 to update
Press 2 to display all contacts
Press 3 to search address book
Press 4 to delete contacts
Press 5 to quit your address book.''')
```

**To add a contact**

```
        if user == '1':
            name = input('Please enter the name of the contact that 
you would like to add.')
            contact = input('Please enter the contact information of 
%s.'%name)
            Name = '\n' + name
            contacts.update( {Name : contact} )
            print('')
            print('%s was added to your adress book!' %name)
            print('')
            write()
```

**To display contact**

```
        elif user == '2':
            print('')
            read()
            print('')
```

**To search contacts**

```
        elif user == '3':
            print('')
            name = input('What is the name of the person whose 
contacts you need?')
            print(contacts['\n' + name])
            print('')
```

**To delete contacts**

```
        elif user == '4':
            print('')
            name = input('Type in the name of the contact that you 
would like to delete.')
            del contacts['\n' + name]
            print('Your contact List has sucessfully deleted %s' 
%name)
            print('')
            write()
```

**To exit**

```
        elif user == '5':
            print('')
            print('Thank you for acessing your adress book!')
            exit()

else:
    exit()
```

Comment: What is the usage for `myLine` and `myContact`? It looks like your `contacts` is a `dict`. If so then you can simply do `contacts[name] = contact` without `myLine` and `myContact`.

Comment: What do you intend `myLine` to be?

Comment: Note that with the current indentation, this discards all but the last row.

Comment: Thanks, but it still spits out some errors....

Comment: Newest error:IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
myLine = name,contact
```

Makes a tuple. You're trying to use a string function on a tuple and that's not possible.

Without seeing the data and expected result I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the code has nothing to do with the `tuple` problem you originally reported.  I suspect you haven't understood the comments or the other answer.  I'll try to explain it more carefully.

You create a `reader` that reads file lines and splits each on the delimiter.  That split produces a list of strings.  In your loop you assign 2 elements of that list to two variables, but throw away all results except the last.  (If you don't understand this, then you need to step back and do some more study of basic Python!)

```
    readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in readCSV:
        name = row[0]
        contact = row[1]
    myLine = name,contact
```

But to address the `tuple` issue, imagine `row` being the result of the `reader` split:

```
In [2]: row = 'one, two'.split(',')                                                                             
In [3]: row                                                                                                     
Out[3]: ['one', ' two']
In [4]: name = row[0]                                                                                           
In [5]: contact = row[1]
```

So `name` and `contact` are two strings; "joining" them with a comma creates a `tuple`:

```
In [6]: myLine = name, contact                                                                                  
In [7]: myLine                                                                                                  
Out[7]: ('one', ' two')               # see the () and ,?
In [8]: type(myLine)                                                                                            
Out[8]: tuple
```

And a `tuple` does not have a split method.  The string in [2] does.

```
In [9]: myLine.split(',')                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8ad056b9add9> in <module>
----> 1 myLine.split(',')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

In Python it's the comma that creates the tuple.  The display includes (), but they aren't necessary.

Maybe you intended to join the two strings into one string, and split that.

```
In [10]: myLine = name + contact                                                                                
In [11]: myLine                                                                                                 
Out[11]: 'one two'
In [12]: myLine.split(',')                                                                                      
Out[12]: ['one two']
```

`+` joins strings, but there's no comma to split one.  There is a `join` method:

```
In [14]: myLine = ','.join([name,contact])                                                                      
In [15]: myLine                                                                                                 
Out[15]: 'one, two'
In [16]: myLine.split(',')                                                                                      
Out[16]: ['one', ' two']
```

But if that's what you intended with:

```
myContact = myLine.split(',')
contacts[myContact[0]] = myContact[1]
```

why not just use?

```
contacts[name] = contact
```

Sorry if I sound pedantic, but that's the nature of programming.  You have to pay attention to every detail (because python is doing that as well).

===

Here's an attempt at reading the `AdressBook` correctly.  Since I don't have such a file, I can't test it, but I think I've got the reads correct:

```
import csv
AdressBook  = '/home/bookworm/AdressBook.txt'
contacts = {}
with open(AdressBook) as file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in readCSV:
        name = row[0]
        contact = row[1]
        contacts[name] = contact
```

Assuming the file has two comma separate strings per line, this should enter all of those in the `contacts` dictionary.